# References between tables and procedures on Informix

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix, procedure

Is there a way to find the relations between tables and procedures in Informix with SQL?
What I'm trying to find is all prodecures that referenses a table that doesn't exist.

I know how i can find the relations for a single procedure in AGS Server Studio but there are almost 1000 procedures in the database.

Comment: Can't you use the 'object reference search' in Server Studio?  You give in the table that doesn't exist and it'll give you a list of all procedures referencing that table.

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea what tables might be missing. This database is quite old and hasn't been very well taken care of.

Comment: Then I don't think you can do this kind of exercise in an automated way...